# How do i fix the Syntax error at input '=' in pinescript v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to optimize the following code:

```
GreenTriggerCond = ta.crossover(FSR, FSRup)
RedTriggerCond = ta.crossunder(FSR, FSRdn)
PreRedTriggerCond = fsr1 > 80
PreGreenTriggerCond = fsr1 < 20
GreenAnchor = GreenAreaCond
BlueAnchor = BlueAreaCond
RedAnchor = RedAreaCond
OrangeAnchor = OrangeAreaCond
GreenTrigger = GreenTriggerCond
RedTrigger = RedTriggerCond
PreGreenTrigger = PreGreenTriggerCond
PreRedTrigger = PreRedTriggerCond

[GreenAnchor01, BlueAnchor01, RedAnchor01, OrangeAnchor01, GreenAreaCond01, BlueAreaCond01, RedAreaCond01, OrangeAreaCond01, fsr01_TF1, LeFV01_TF1, EMA01_TF1, price01] = request.security(ticker.modify(s01, syminfo.session), TF1, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, GreenAnchor, BlueAnchor, RedAnchor, OrangeAnchor, fsr1, LeFV1, EMA100, close])
[GreenAnchor02, BlueAnchor02, RedAnchor02, OrangeAnchor02, GreenAreaCond02, BlueAreaCond02, RedAreaCond02, OrangeAreaCond02, fsr02_TF1, LeFV02_TF1, EMA02_TF1, price02] = request.security(ticker.modify(s02, syminfo.session), TF1, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, GreenAnchor, BlueAnchor, RedAnchor, OrangeAnchor, fsr1, LeFV1, EMA100, close])
[GreenAnchor03, BlueAnchor03, RedAnchor03, OrangeAnchor03, GreenAreaCond03, BlueAreaCond03, RedAreaCond03, OrangeAreaCond03, fsr03_TF1, LeFV03_TF1, EMA03_TF1, price03] = request.security(ticker.modify(s03, syminfo.session), TF1, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, GreenAnchor, BlueAnchor, RedAnchor, OrangeAnchor, fsr1, LeFV1, EMA100, close])
[GreenAnchor04, BlueAnchor04, RedAnchor04, OrangeAnchor04, GreenAreaCond04, BlueAreaCond04, RedAreaCond04, OrangeAreaCond04, fsr04_TF1, LeFV04_TF1, EMA04_TF1, price04] = request.security(ticker.modify(s04, syminfo.session), TF1, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, GreenAnchor, BlueAnchor, RedAnchor, OrangeAnchor, fsr1, LeFV1, EMA100, close])
[GreenAnchor05, BlueAnchor05, RedAnchor05, OrangeAnchor05, GreenAreaCond05, BlueAreaCond05, RedAreaCond05, OrangeAreaCond05, fsr05_TF1, LeFV05_TF1, EMA05_TF1, price05] = request.security(ticker.modify(s05, syminfo.session), TF1, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, GreenAnchor, BlueAnchor, RedAnchor, OrangeAnchor, fsr1, LeFV1, EMA100, close])

[GreenAnchor21, BlueAnchor21, RedAnchor21, OrangeAnchor21, GreenAreaCond21, BlueAreaCond21, RedAreaCond21, OrangeAreaCond21, fsr21_TF2, LeFV21_TF2, GreenTrigger01,RedTrigger01, PreGreenTrigger01, PreRedTrigger01, price21] = request.security(ticker.modify(s01, syminfo.session), TF2, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, GreenAnchor, BlueAnchor, RedAnchor, OrangeAnchor, fsr1, LeFV1, GreenTriggerCond,RedTriggerCond, PreGreenTriggerCond,PreRedTriggerCond, close])
[GreenAnchor22, BlueAnchor22, RedAnchor22, OrangeAnchor22, GreenAreaCond22, BlueAreaCond22, RedAreaCond22, OrangeAreaCond22, fsr22_TF2, LeFV22_TF2, GreenTrigger02,RedTrigger02, PreGreenTrigger02, PreRedTrigger02, price22] = request.security(ticker.modify(s02, syminfo.session), TF2, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, GreenAnchor, BlueAnchor, RedAnchor, OrangeAnchor, fsr1, LeFV1, GreenTriggerCond,RedTriggerCond, PreGreenTriggerCond,PreRedTriggerCond, close])
[GreenAnchor23, BlueAnchor23, RedAnchor23, OrangeAnchor23, GreenAreaCond23, BlueAreaCond23, RedAreaCond23, OrangeAreaCond23, fsr23_TF2, LeFV23_TF2, GreenTrigger03,RedTrigger03, PreGreenTrigger03, PreRedTrigger03, price23] = request.security(ticker.modify(s03, syminfo.session), TF2, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, GreenAnchor, BlueAnchor, RedAnchor, OrangeAnchor, fsr1, LeFV1, GreenTriggerCond,RedTriggerCond, PreGreenTriggerCond,PreRedTriggerCond, close])
[GreenAnchor24, BlueAnchor24, RedAnchor24, OrangeAnchor24, GreenAreaCond24, BlueAreaCond24, RedAreaCond24, OrangeAreaCond24, fsr24_TF2, LeFV24_TF2, GreenTrigger04,RedTrigger04, PreGreenTrigger04, PreRedTrigger04, price24] = request.security(ticker.modify(s04, syminfo.session), TF2, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, GreenAnchor, BlueAnchor, RedAnchor, OrangeAnchor, fsr1, LeFV1, GreenTriggerCond,RedTriggerCond, PreGreenTriggerCond,PreRedTriggerCond, close])
[GreenAnchor25, BlueAnchor25, RedAnchor25, OrangeAnchor25, GreenAreaCond25, BlueAreaCond25, RedAreaCond25, OrangeAreaCond25, fsr25_TF2, LeFV25_TF2, GreenTrigger05,RedTrigger05, PreGreenTrigger05, PreRedTrigger05, price25] = request.security(ticker.modify(s05, syminfo.session), TF2, [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, GreenAnchor, BlueAnchor, RedAnchor, OrangeAnchor, fsr1, LeFV1, GreenTriggerCond,RedTriggerCond, PreGreenTriggerCond,PreRedTriggerCond, close])
```

This is the new code that I came up with to loop through the above code.  I am getting a syntax error on this line GreenAnchor[i] = securityRes1[0].  I have also tried := instead and get the same error.  How do I fix this?

```
var bool[] GreenAnchor = array.new_bool(40)
var bool[] BlueAnchor = array.new_bool(40)
var bool[] RedAnchor = array.new_bool(40)
var bool[] OrangeAnchor = array.new_bool(40)
var bool[] GreenTrigger = array.new_bool(40)
var bool[] RedTrigger = array.new_bool(40)
var bool[] PreGreenTrigger = array.new_bool(40)
var bool[] PreRedTrigger = array.new_bool(40)

for i = 0 to 4
    var securityRes1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid + "s" + tostring(i + 1), "D", [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, FSR, LeFV, EMA100, close])
    GreenAnchor[i] = securityRes1[0]
    BlueAnchor[i] = securityRes1[1]
    RedAnchor[i] = securityRes1[2]
    OrangeAnchor[i] = securityRes1[3]

    var securityRes2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid + "s" + tostring(i + 1), "D", [GreenAreaCond, BlueAreaCond, RedAreaCond, OrangeAreaCond, FSR, LeFV, GreenTriggerCond, RedTriggerCond, PreGreenTriggerCond, PreRedTriggerCond, close])
    GreenTrigger[i] = securityRes2[8]
    RedTrigger[i] = securityRes2[9]
    PreGreenTrigger[i] = securityRes2[10]
    PreRedTrigger[i] = securityRes2[11]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are MANY issues with this code.

To answer your question, if you want to assign some value to an already declared variable, you should use the `:=` operator.

Also, you should learn how [arrays](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html) and [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) work in pinescript before attempting this. You should be using `array.get()` and `array.set()` functions for a start.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will let CHATGPT know there are many issues with this code since that's where it came from..... haha